# Prolog: Choosing NOT to insert an element during list recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I've made a predicate that takes 2 list as arguments and returns a list concatenated with the product of "recipesub", however I need to make a third rule that prohibits the product from being inserted if the product at hand is an empty list.

So the first list could look like this:

```
recipe([ingredient(rice,4),ingredient(salt,3),ingredient(water,5)]).
```

And the second one like this:

```
ingredients([ingredient(rice,3),ingredient(salt,4),ingredient(water,4),
```

At the moment it returns: `List = [ingredient(rice,1),[],ingredient(water,1)]`

I WANT it to return: `List = [ingredient(rice,1),ingredient(water,1)]`

```
need_to_buy([],_,List):- List = [].
need_to_buy([H|Hs],[X|Xs],[Difference|List]):-
   H = ingredient(Type,Amount),
   recipesub(Type,Amount,[X|Xs],Difference),
   need_to_buy(Hs,[X|Xs],List).
```

Below is how far I've gotten with the solution.

```
/*need_to_buy([H|Hs],[X|Xs],List):-
   H = ingredient(Type,Amount),
   recipesub(Type,Amount,[X|Xs],Difference),
   Difference = [],
   need_to_buy(Hs,[X|Xs],List).*/
```

And this is the support-predicate, recipesub.

```
recipesub(Type,Amount,[],Difference):-
    Difference = ingredient(Type,Amount).
recipesub(Type,Amount,[Z|_],Difference):-
    Z = ingredient(Type,Stock),
    Amount>Stock,
    NewAmount is Amount-Stock,
    Difference = ingredient(Type,NewAmount).
recipesub(Type,Amount,[Z|_],Difference):-
    Z = ingredient(Type, Stock),
    Stock >= Amount,
    Difference = [].
recipesub(Type,Amount,[Z|Zs],Difference):-
    Z = ingredient(WrongType,_),
    WrongType \= Type,
    recipesub(Type,Amount,Zs,Difference).
```

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.  What is this `recipesub/4`?

Comment: Recipesub is a predicate which recursively compares the head of the first list to each of the elements in the second list, if the variavble "Amount" in "H" turns out to be smaller than the "Amount" in X, it returns difference = ingredient(type,requiredAmount), But if the variable Amount in X turns out to be larger than the variable Amount in H, then it returns an empty list.

Comment: Ok sorry, I´ve now rectified to the best of my ability.

Comment: You could either check for `[]` (return from `recipesub`) in your `need_to_buy` predicate, or you could have `recipesub` fail instead of offering `[]` as the solution, and have `need_to_buy` "do the right thing" when `recipesub` fails.

Answer (score 1):

I normally don't do a bunch of nested conditionals but it "felt right" this time, and this is the solution I found:

```
need_to_buy([], _, []).
need_to_buy([ingredient(Type, AmountNeeded)|Ingredients], OnHand, Needed) :-
    % Do we have any on-hand?
    member(ingredient(Type, AmountOnHand), OnHand) ->

        % If the amount on-hand is greater than the amount needed, 
        % just hand off the rest
        (AmountOnHand >= AmountNeeded ->
             need_to_buy(Ingredients, OnHand, Needed)

         % otherwise, calculate the amount needed and recur
         ; (AmountToBuy is AmountNeeded - AmountOnHand,
            need_to_buy(Ingredients, OnHand, RestNeeded),
            Needed = [ingredient(Type, AmountToBuy)|RestNeeded]))

    % If we have none on-hand, we can just use the amount needed
    % to form the request, and recur
    ; need_to_buy(Ingredients, OnHand, RestNeeded),
      Needed = [ingredient(Type, AmountNeeded)|RestNeeded].
```

Otherwise I think you'll have a lot of fairly inefficient testing and retesting. The main mistake I see in your code is that you're pattern matching on the second argument. It's easier to rely on `member/2` or `memberchk/2` to do the dirty work of finding the right ingredient in the stuff you have on-hand.

If I did it with a bunch of clauses instead it would probably look like this:

```
need_to_buy([], _, []).

% case 1: we don't have the ingredient at all
need_to_buy([ingredient(Type, AmountNeeded) | Ingredients],
            OnHand,
            [ingredient(Type, AmountNeeded)|Needed]) :-
    \+ memberchk(ingredient(Type, _), OnHand),
    need_to_buy(Ingredients, OnHand, Needed).

% case 2: we have it, but not enough
need_to_buy([ingredient(Type, AmountNeeded) | Ingredients],
            OnHand,
            [ingredient(Type, AmountToBuy)|RestNeeded]) :-
    memberchk(ingredient(Type, AmountOnHand), OnHand),
    AmountNeeded > AmountOnHand,
    AmountToBuy is AmountNeeded - AmountOnHand,
    need_to_buy(Ingredients, OnHand, RestNeeded).

% case 3: we have enough
need_to_buy([ingredient(Type, AmountNeeded) | Ingredients],
            OnHand,
            RestNeeded) :-
    memberchk(ingredient(Type, AmountOnHand), OnHand),
    AmountNeeded =< AmountOnHand,
    need_to_buy(Ingredients, OnHand, RestNeeded).
```

This leaves a choice point on the stack and just generally seems like a lot of retesting the same conditions and re-traversal for my taste. But if it looks better to you it should work the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but by the time I saw your code I had already come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately solved it by splitting the second rule of need_to_buy into two rules, one which handles the case where difference is an empty list, and on where it isnt an empty list.

I had some trouble with it at first but it turns out the "orientation" of the rules was giving me trouble, so I had to place the rule which handles the case where Difference \= [], above the one where Difference = [].
It now looks like this:

```
need_to_buy([],_,List):- List = [].
need_to_buy([H|Hs],[X|Xs],[Difference|List]):-
   H = ingredient(Type,Amount),
   recipesub(Type,Amount,[X|Xs],Difference),
   Difference \= [],
   need_to_buy(Hs,[X|Xs],List).
need_to_buy([H|Hs],[X|Xs],List):-
   H = ingredient(Type,Amount),
   recipesub(Type,Amount,[X|Xs],Difference),
   Difference = [],
   need_to_buy(Hs,[X|Xs],List).
```